# Update newest row with data from oldest row in mysql

Tags: mysql

How can i update certain fields in my table with data from older entries?

Example Table:

```
    id | timestamp    | columne1| columne2
    ---------------------------------------
    1  | 2015-07-20...| 078888  | *****
    2  | 2015-07-19...| 155896  | value 2.2
    3  | 2015-07-07...| 278831  | value 2.3
    4  | 2015-07-01...| 078888  | value 2.4
```

I am trying to update columne2 from row 1 with the value in same columne2 row 4.

Comment: The schema you gave us and your query are completely different. Can you update one or the other in your question?

Comment: i am not sure my query was even going the right way so i deleted it. The Principe is actually the same as explained in the schema.

Comment: So do you just want to always insert the data from the oldest (as based on the `timestamp` column) `columne2`  whenever you run your insert query?

Comment: exactly... i want to run this query so it updates all rows matching my where clause though! For axample: where "timestamp" < NOW(). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

**plan**

> - select the minimum entries (maxs) grouped by columne1,
> - select the maximum entries (mins) grouped by columne1,
> - join calls to maxs to mins
> - set calls.columne2 value from mins data

**query**

```
update
calls c
inner join
(
  select c1.*, q1.min_ts, q1.max_ts
  from calls c1
  inner join
  ( select columne1, min(`timestamp`) min_ts, max(`timestamp`) as max_ts from calls group by columne1 ) q1
  on c1.columne1 = q1.columne1
  where c1.`timestamp` = q1.max_ts
) maxs
on c.id = maxs.id
inner join
(
  select c1.*, q1.min_ts, q1.max_ts
  from calls c1
  inner join
  ( select columne1, min(`timestamp`) min_ts, max(`timestamp`) as max_ts from calls group by columne1 ) q1
  on c1.columne1 = q1.columne1
  where c1.`timestamp` = q1.min_ts
) mins
on maxs.columne1 = mins.columne1
set c.columne2 = mins.columne2
;
```

**output**

```
+----+------------------+----------+-----------+
| id |    timestamp     | columne1 | columne2  |
+----+------------------+----------+-----------+
|  1 | 2015-07-20 12:00 |   078888 | value 2.4 |
|  2 | 2015-07-19 12:00 |   155896 | value 2.2 |
|  3 | 2015-07-07 12:00 |   278831 | value 2.3 |
|  4 | 2015-07-01 12:00 |   078888 | value 2.4 |
+----+------------------+----------+-----------+
```

**[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c100f/1)**